# Why does Installing Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image v2 fail

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, wear-os

I am using Visual Studio and Xamarin's **Android SDK Manager** to try to install **Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image** for Android 9.0.

[image]

After I click **Apply Changles**, the download finishes and the install is attempted. After, I see a message that says **Installing Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image v2 failed** with no additional information about why.

[image]

How can I solve this problem, or how can I diagnose why the installation might be failing?

Edit: I do have **Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image** for **Android 8.0** already installed, in case that helps provides any useful information.

Comment: Something is out of sync as the current Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image is at revision "3" not 2. (`https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/x86-28_r03.zip`) Personally I use Android Studio to install and keep up to date the Android SDK Platform and Tools....

Comment: when do you use the Atom 64 image and when do you use the one that doesn't have 64 in its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Cause:**

Actually, Microsoft maintained its own `repository`, the purpose is that before the Microsoft maintained its own repository, there were often times when Google would push updates that broke `Xamarin.Android`. Microsoft maintaining its own repository for the SDK mitigates this issue since new pushes from Google can be vetted by XA team.

**Solution:**

> By default, the Android SDK Manager downloads platform components and
>   tools from a Microsoft-managed repository. If you need access to
>   experimental alpha/beta platforms and tools that are not yet available
>   in the Microsoft repository, you can switch the SDK Manager to use
>   Google's repository. To make this switch, click the gear icon in the
>   lower right-hand corner and select Repository > Google (Unsupported).

Open `Android SDK Manager` -> Click the `gear icon` at the right of `Apply Changes` --> `Repository` --> Select `Google`.

And then, you can install `Wear OS Intel x86 Atom System Image`.

You can refer: [respository-selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=macos#respository-selection-1).

Comment: So when is MSFT going to vet and release a vetted version?